# how to positioning <fieldset> tag?

Tags: html, css, web, css-position, fieldset

I want to put the **fieldset** on **Center**.

**Html code:**

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #f42b68;
      width: 100%;
    }
    fieldset {
      height: 50%;
      width: 80%;
      background: #ffffff;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <center>
    <fieldset>
      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="txt">
      </form>
    </fieldset>
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any possible way to do it other than using `center` **tag?**

Comment: fieldset is suppose to be a child of form, not the opposite :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target the `input` itself rather than the `fieldset`, as the `input` has `text-align: start` by default. What you're looking for is:

```
fieldset input {
  text-align: center;
}
```

To align the fieldet *itself*, it behaves a little differently, as it is a block element, rather than text. To align a block element centrally, you need to give it `margin: auto`. This can also be used with images (or any other element) by explicitly defining them as a block element with `display: block`:

```
fieldset {
  margin: auto;
}
```

Keep in mind that `margin: auto` is stating that all four margins should have automatic offsets (centralised). That includes the top and bottom margins. You can align just the left and right margins with shorthand `margin: 0 auto`.

Updated code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #f42b68;
  width: 100%;
}
fieldset {
  height: 50%;
  width: 80%;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
fieldset input {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <fieldset>
    <form>
      <input type="text" placeholder="txt">
    </form>
  </fieldset>
</body>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You forget to remove the `<center>` tags from the html.

Comment: See, I have put <fieldset under <center> tag. I am asking that without using <center> can I place the fieldset in center, not the content of fieldset.

Comment: The `<center>` tag does absolutely nothing in HTML. It won't align the content to the center, nor will it break any existing logic by including it. It's useless though, so I've updated my code to remove it :)

Comment: @stodgy.nerd -- Ahh, you want the *fieldset* to be centralised. I'll update my answer again now :)

Comment: I've just updated this answer to cover centralised the fieldset itself. Hopefully this is what you were looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `text-align` and `margin` to you fieldset. This will produce the same results as your code without the `<center>` tag.

```css
body
{
    background-color: #f42b68;
    width: 100%;
}
fieldset
{
    height: 50%;
    width: 80%;
    background: #ffffff;
    text-align:center;
    margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<body>

<fieldset>
    <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="txt">
    </form>
</fieldset>

</body>
```

Comment: I am not asking for the content of <fieldset>, I wrote <fieldset> under <center> to align the fieldset on center but I want to know can I do it without using <center> tag